# selecting data with fql and inserting into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm experiencing a problem with an operation.

I'm using FQL to extract the number of likes for each post of my forum, but i can't understand how to select the number from the link_stat and put it in my mysql table.

Here's my example. Thanks in advice.

```
$ret = $facebook->api(array(
         'method' => 'fql.query',
         'query' => 'SELECT like_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = "https://www.facebook.com/cameoeastbourneclub?fref=ts"'
                        ));

                        foreach ($ret as $value) {
                            echo $value['like_count'];
                        }

                        $rets = $ret[0]['like_count'];

                        mysql_query("INSERT INTO annunci (fblike) VALUES ('".$rets."')");
                        echo $sql;
                        mysql_query($sql);
```

If i echo the statements it says me that it inserts the correct value, but if i make a sql statement in my mysql db it does nothing

Do you know which way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Where do you declare `$sql`?

Comment: Look at your `php_error.log` to find the error.

Comment: that file shows me nothing. here what i wrote. It display me the correct statement but don't affect        $sql = "INSERT INTO annunci (fblike) VALUES (".$rets.")";
       echo $sql;
       mysql_query($sql);
       } catch (ErrorException $e) {
        $e->getMessage(); 
       }

Comment: You are catching the error but you don't actually `echo` the error message...

Comment: Seems that there are no errors

Comment: Solved. It was an error regarding connection to the database. Always set error_reporting to all.